# Detect if a script is being run via shebang or was specified as a command line argument

Tags: bash, shebang

In the Pyenv project, we've had a peculiar problem.

We are substituting `python` (and `python*`) with our Bash scripts ("shims") that select a Python executable to run at runtime.

Now, [some users wish to use a special selection logic](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1813) when a Python script is run as `path/to/script.py`. The problem is, this logic should NOT apply if the script is instead run as `<python> path/to/script.py`!

**Is there a way to reliably distinguish these two cases?**

I wasn't able to find anything: depending on the way command line arguments are formulated in the 2nd case, the exact same command line could be executed in both cases:
<sub>(the Bash script given is not a real shim, just a demonstration example to showcase what our logic sees and does)</sub>

```
$ cat python3 
#!/bin/bash
echo "'$0'"
for a in "$@"; do
  echo "'$a'"
done
# need to do the detection here
exec python3 "$@"

$ cat t.py 
#!/home/vmuser/python3
import sys
print(sys.argv)

$ $PWD/t.py
'/home/vmuser/python3' 
'/home/vmuser/t.py'
['/home/vmuser/t.py']

$ $PWD/python3 $PWD/t.py 
'/home/vmuser/python3'
'/home/vmuser/t.py'
['/home/vmuser/t.py']
```

Since shebang is a Linux kernel feature -- maybe it sets some indicator that this mechanism has been used?

---

We've considered [requiring users to use a special shebang in their Python scripts](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1813#issuecomment-778755503) that they wish to apply the special logic to, but [that idea proved unpopular](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1813#issuecomment-808966324) because it makes those scripts unportable.

Comment: Have a look at [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582943/how-do-i-know-if-my-python-script-has-been-called-with-the-interpreter-on-the-co).

Comment: @Quasímodo the linked question requires a special shebang that's not usable outside of Pyenv. [We had such an idea](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1813#issuecomment-778755503) but it [proved unpopular with users](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1813#issuecomment-808966324) because it makes scripts unportable.

Comment: Can you create a "launcher" script/binary (in python, compiled c, or whatever you choose) as an option? I.E., the launcher can be version agnostic in itself, and selects the appropriate python* interpreter to pass the rest of the script to. Doing this, you can also allow your end-users methods to pass additional information, such as in specially formatted comments in the first few lines, to give it any additional hints/directions.

Comment: You might be interested in [python-exec](https://github.com/mgorny/python-exec). I have no idea how much actual overlap there is with your use case, but I suspect they had to solve some of the same problems as you are facing.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn [we've had that idea, too](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1918#issuecomment-841888379), and that's what we currently suggest as an alternative to the requested feature -- [a plugin](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1918#issuecomment-842261656) that allows to create a separate set of manually configured shims for select scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since shebang is a Linux kernel feature -- maybe it sets some indicator that this mechanism has been used?

Yes, it does. Linux sets the `AT_EXECFN` auxiliar vector entry to the path of the original executable. In C, you can do it with `char *at_execfn = (char*)getauxval(AT_EXECFN)`, followed by `stat(at_execfn)`, etc.

Getting it from bash is tricky, though. You can try unpacking the `/proc/self/auxv` and then looking through `/proc/self/mem`. Good luck with that ;-)

Comment: Well, that does it... If I use a C program equivalent instead of the Bash script, `at_execfn` is `/home/vmuser/t.py` in the 1st case and `/home/vmuser/python3` in the 2nd. But then the question arises how to do this in other OSes. We officially support MacOS as well, it's BSD-based.

Comment: I'll check if MacOS has an equivalent to `AT_EXECFN`

Comment: You could check if among these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe/1024937#1024937 some wouldn't work like AT_EXECFN (rather than falling back to OP's initial problem)?

Comment: @A.B no dice. Both `_dyld_get_image_name` and `_NSGetExecutablePath` give post-shebang name.

Comment: Asked about MacOS at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238888/get-pre-shebang-executable-path-equivalent-to-getauxvalat-execfn